# JSON - return id's if item contains a label - Python

Tags: python, json

For this json data I have loaded. How can I return all the "id" values for items that contain "label"?

```
import json
data = json.dumps({"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}})
```

I can access an individual element however cannot create a loop that iterates all id's containing a label.

This is how I individually access an item.

```
loadData = json.loads(data)
loadData
items = loadData['menu']['items'][1]
print(items['label'])
```

Comment: if "label" in...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a static structure that always has the given keys:

```
[d["id"] for d in loadData["menu"]["items"] if "label" in d]
```

will get you a list of all ids...

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all the elements of `loadData['menu']['items']` and check if 'label' is present.

Code :

```
loadData = json.loads(data)
items = loadData['menu']['items']
for item in items:
    if 'label' in item.keys():
        print 'Label Found'
```